# How to spell the sound that happens when you stick your tongue outside of your mouth and gently blow

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography, sounds, onomatopoeia

When you stick your tongue outside of your mouth and gently blow, it makes a common sound to indicate "whatever!" or "I don't like your answer/response" or "Yes, you are smarter than I am."

What is the name of this sound and how do you spell the sound?

Comment: :P thbbpt. <filler>

Comment: See [*blowing a raspberry* on Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_a_raspberry), which says the sound can be transcribed in IPA as the unvoiced linguolabial trill [r̼̊], and is "commonly spelled" *pbbbt* on the internet.

Comment: I'm thinking I've generally seen it spelled with an initial T.

Comment: @HotLicks I tend to agree, hence the scare quotes around the phrase "commonly spelled" from Wikipedia (which, even there, is marked with [citation needed]).

Comment: [Bill the Cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_the_Cat) "spells" it "Thbbft" (and possibly other ways).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - There you have it!  No need to search for a better authority!

Comment: @DanBron Interesting. When I see _pbbbt_, my immediate reaction is to interpret it as representing [ʙ̯ː] (an unvoiced bilabial trill or what is also often spelt as _pfffft_ when indicating indifference, or _prrrr_ when indicating a horse neighing).

Comment: Is the "Bronx cheer" precisely the same as the British raspberry? I've often wondered. I blow my raspberries against the back of my hand, which makes for a much louder and more insulting noise. How would Janus and Dan phoneticise that? Robin, I don't see the raspberry as carrying your third meaning at all. I would say, Whatever, I don't like your answer, or go and fornicate elsewhere.

Comment: "Yes, a raspberry is a 'wet' sound made with by blowing air through wet lips 'blocked' by the tongue. Whereas, a 'pffffttt' is made by forcing air through a (dry) lower lip and front teeth." – 5arx [What's the verb for making that “pffft” sound?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47529/whats-the-verb-for-making-that-pffft-sound/47552#47552)

Comment: @DavidPugh "Raspberry" is short for "raspberry tart", which is rhyming slang. So that perhaps explains what a raspberry sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder what the linguists will make of this question.

It sounds as though you are describing what is colloquially known as 'Blowing a Rasberry'.

As to how you would represent it in writing, I'm a bit flummoxed. Experiment with the following (all as long or short as you wish);

Brthrthrthrthrth

Pthwrzrthwrzzz.....

Much better than the internet Pbbt. You could have started something here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you are looking for is ["pfft"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pfft), defined as:

> An expression of a lack of interest in another persons comment

Blowing a raspberry is something different, and noticeably more insulting.

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned poking your tongue out, which makes me think this is a raspberry, and not a 'pfft'.

Answer (score -2):

Blowing air between loosely closed lips like ppbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb is called Pursed, or Pursed lips.

Comment: Don't you make pursed lips without a sound, though?

Comment: Pursed lips don't usually involve the tongue sticking out, which is what the OP describes.